# What is the best way to write faster on Vim using a non-english keyboard?

Tags: vim, layout, keyboard, shortcut

I usually use Vim, and its great for the ability to do faster some actions than other editors. However, since I live in Argentina I have a Latin American keyboard, that makes everything in Vim pretty slower (to write / to search, I must press Shift+7).

Since I don't want to be changing Keyboard layouts all the time (and its pretty difficult to get used to pressing symbols as in an English keyboard), I was wondering if there was a vim plugin (of .vimrc file) that may be useful for international users.

Just for the sake of it, here's how the Latin American keyboard is laid out:

[image]
<sub>(source: [support at pages.slc.edu](http://pages.slc.edu/~support/files/keyboard-layout-spanish-latin-american.png))</sub>

By the way, I would love to go and buy an English keyboard, but unfortunately I use a Laptop.

Comment: I thought changing the keyboard layout was as easy as pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F2 (at least in Windows/DOS)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sympathize. You have at least a couple of options:

1. Since you said you'd love to buy an English keyboard, I'd recommend just changing your keyboard layout.  on Windows you can do so under Regional Settings. On a basic Linux console you can use `loadkeys`.  Under X11 you can use `setxkbmap`.
2. Just live with it the way it is. The vim help will make the most sense this way.
3. Search for a language map for your latin american keyboard.  For instance, take a look at [this one for dvorak](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout).

I use the Dvorak keyboard layout and I just live with it the way it is. If there's a command or two that are very cumbersome, map them to something easy on your keyboard. There will inevitably be other shortcuts that are easier because of the different keyboard layout, but overall efficiency will depend on your layout and what features you use.

Comment: You have a typo: `setxkbmap`, not `setxbmap`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would be better changing my keyboard layout every time I use Vim. Luckily, I found a way in GNOME to change layouts with the Caps Lock key, so I guess I found an actual use to it.

Comment: use langmap option in vim

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [translit3](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3056) plugin to enter non-latin1 symbols on latin1 keyboard. Just choose one keyboard layout and write a transliteration table in order to use other symbols.